React-PDF Causes iPhone 13 and Below to Crash on PDF Display in Next.js App
I’m working on a Next.js project that involves displaying PDFs using the react-pdf library. The issue arises on iPhone 13 and older models, where the app crashes after displaying a PDF. The PDF initially loads fine, but then the page reloads after a second with an error: "A problem repeatedly occurred."
Project Details:

React Version: 18
Next.js Version: 14
react-pdf: Version 9.1.1
Browser: Safari on iPhone 13 and below (iOS 15/16)
Error Message: "A problem repeatedly occurred"

Problem Description:

When displaying a PDF using react-pdf, the PDF is rendered fine, but
after a short moment, the page reloads with the error mentioned
above.
The issue only occurs on iPhone 13 and older models. No issues on
newer iPhones, Android, or desktop browsers.
This problem does not occur when only a single PDF is rendered, but
when multiple PDFs are displayed, the crash is more frequent.

Code Setup:
I’m using the following basic structure for rendering the PDF:
Parent component:
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const PDFCard = dynamic(() => import("../PDFCard"), { ssr: false });
...

PDFCard
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

if (typeof Promise.withResolvers === "undefined") {
  if (window) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    window.Promise.withResolvers = function () {
      let resolve, reject;
      const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res;
        reject = rej;
      });
      return { promise, resolve, reject };
    };
  }
}

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  "https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@4.4.168/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs";

const PDFCard = ({ pdf }: { pdf: string }) => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(0);

  const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }: { numPages: number }) => {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePageWidth = () => {
      const containerWidth =
        document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(".pdf-container")?.offsetWidth ||
        500;
      setPageWidth(containerWidth);
    };

    updatePageWidth();
    window.addEventListener("resize", updatePageWidth);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updatePageWidth);
  }, []);

  if (!pdf) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
     <div className="pdf-container">
         <Document file={pdf} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
            {Array.from({ length: numPages }, (_, index) => (
              <Page
                key={`page_${index + 1}`}
                pageNumber={index + 1}
                renderAnnotationLayer={false}
                renderTextLayer={false}
                width={pageWidth}
              />
            ))}
       </Document>
     </div>
  );
};

Attempts to Fix:

Polyfills: I tried adding a polyfill for Promise.withResolvers (which was missing in some browsers).
Worker Configuration: I ensured that the pdf.js worker is loaded properly using:
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@4.4.168/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs";
Responsive PDF Rendering: The PDFs are responsive, scaling based on
the container width, and I’ve set up useEffect to handle resizing
dynamically.
tried
tried to use renderMode="svg" but seems not to available any more on my version

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with PDF rendering on older iPhones? Is there a way to resolve the app crash, such as optimizing the rendering process, limiting the number of PDFs loaded at once, or other approaches? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
